# Where does this gasket go? Countertop dishwasher faucet adapter

Tags: faucet, dishwasher, adapter

I have an SPT brand countertop dishwasher. I forgot to push the red drain button before disconnecting the hose from the faucet adapter. The water pressure blew off this black rubber gasket. I can’t seem to figure out where it needs to go in order to make a nice tight seal again that won’t soak my kitchen when I turn on the water!

[image: photo]
[image: photo]
[image: photo]
[image: photo]
[image: photo]

Comment: top picture ... the bottom end of the silver piece ... that is were it needs to be when the diverter is pushed onto the metal piece

Comment: In the groove of the silver piece just below the serrated edge

Comment: 2nd photo: push it into the groove just above the ball bearings.

Comment: If it goes in the silver piece’s groove, then there is a trick to it because it isn’t creating a seal. Likewise if i am not sure what “groove above the ball bearings” to look for or anything. I’ve tried a few places but none seem to be doing the trick so far. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: I think @ojait has it.The ball bearings 'lock' into the beveled groove on the silver piece.  This will create a pressure and the round tip of the silver piece should press into the gasket.

Comment: Yeah. I would have said that was below, which was throwing me off. I submitted an answer. Thanks, all

Answer (score 3):

[image]
[image]

I figured it out. I’m not sure if this is the groove @ojait was referring to or not, but I was able to maneuver the rubber gasket into the spot inside the female side of the adapter below the ball bearings. I used a chopstick. The seal now is slightly leaky, exactly like it was until I messed things up yesterday. Thanks to all for taking a look!

Comment: try wrapping faucet flange with Teflon tape  a couple of times it may help stop leak.

Comment: @ojatt thread tape is unliely to help much on a push connector.

Comment: FWIW, I have added a few layers of Teflon tape to the faucet flange as suggested and it did reduce leaking. That said, I am sure it would be even more effective on a threaded connector.